# Correctness of a context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request

> But time by time lots of theory and experiments made their assumption wrong.

Is there anything in using *time by time* in the above sentence whereas it refers changing things with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Time by time* is not an English idiom.

You may use timespans like this—*hour by hour*, *day by day*, *year by year*—but that expression means “in each succeding *timespan*” and is used with a following comparative like *more*:

> Year by year it became more obvious that their assumption was wrong.

If what you mean is “repeatedly, over many *timespans*” you may say “*timespan* after *timespan*”:

> Year after year, experiments and developing theory repeatedly proved their assumption wrong.

You may also use *time* in this construction; but here *time* does not signify a *timespan* but an *occasion*:

> Time after time, experiments and ...